# Sort form when opening based on previous form criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a search form that runs a query and populates a subform within the search form. After querying and populating the subform you can click on a specific record ID to open a subsequent form specific and filtered to the record KEY ("ID") that was clicked on in the previous subform.

This code works great when the "ID" key field is a Number type format:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormToOpen", , , "ID = " & Me.ID, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

However, when querying to build the subform it does not consider the leading zero i.e. if a record ID is "0123456" and the user enters "0123456" the query returns no results. If you enter "123456" it WILL return the record.

So I switched to the ShortText datatype and the query works great! You can enter  "0123456" or  "123456" and return the record...problem is that the open subsequent form code then breaks with the short text type.

This is my query criteria:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![FORMNAME]![txtID] & "*"
```

I believe I can change the form open code so that it recognizes a text type instead of a number type--something like:

```
 ID = " & "Me.ID"
```

Or, would it be better to change my query criteria? TYIA!

*Update*
This works great if it is a text data type: DoCmd.OpenForm "SecondFormName", , , "FieldName = '" & Me.ControlName & "'" '(note, that's a double quote, single quote and double quote at the end) I found it here: baldyweb.com/wherecondition.htm –

Comment: why change the datatype? you can use `CInt(Me.ID)` it will remove the leading zero so even if the user enter `00123456` still you get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, but I am not familiar with "CInt" where and how would I use that? With the "me." I am assuming in the form or subform I tried adding it to the on click event of the record ID:  `DoCmd.OpenForm "FormToOpen", , , "ID = " & CInt(Me.ID), acFormEdit, acWindowNormal`  and it didn't work... TYIA! –

Comment: This works great if it is a text data type: `DoCmd.OpenForm "SecondFormName", , , "FieldName = '" & Me.ControlName & "'"  '(note, that's a double quote, single quote and double quote at the end)` I found it here: http://www.baldyweb.com/wherecondition.htm